# Help with installing Gnome Shell Google Calendar Extension

Tags: gnome, python, gnome-shell-extension

I am having trouble running the script to install the gnome-shell-google-calendar extension into Gnome Shell. I keep getting this:

```
rafael@Raf:~$ ./calendar/gnome-shell-google-calendar.py
Logging in as 'None'...
Please choose the Account: I enter my email here
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./calendar/gnome-shell-google-calendar.py", line 455, in <module>
    account = oauth.oauth_prompt()
  File "/home/rafael/calendar/oauth.py", line 25, in oauth_prompt
    email = accounts[int(raw_input('Please choose the Account: '))]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'email address'
```

I replaced my actual email address with the words email address for privacy purposes.

A bit more info on this extension can be found here:
https://github.com/jnns/gnome-shell-google-calendar
http://maketecheasier.com/integrate-google-calendar-into-gnome-shell/2011/10/04

Is there a way of fixing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I found the solution to my problem:
First I added my google account to Online Accounts

Then I followed the steps in this tutorial exactly:
http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/google-calendar-gnome-shell-integration.html

Works perfect now :)

Comment: While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 3):

I've tried to run the version you have, but it didn't even ask me my email address, however I had a working version from https://github.com/vintitres/gnome-shell-google-calendar for a few months already. It has even added features like excluding calendars from importing.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up your Google account in Online Accounts (System Settings -> Online Accounts). Once you've done that, run the script again and you will see a list of Google Accounts with numbers to their left. At the prompt enter the number for the account you want to use, and voila - works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the script is expecting a number to select between a list of address, not a new address.

```
accounts[int(raw_input('Please choose the Account: '))]
```

It's using your input as a list index (most likely, it could be a dictionary too, but them casting it to a int doesn't make sense).